# Uncaught SyntaxError: Setter must have exactly one formal parameter

Tags: javascript, setter

I'm trying to understand getters and setters on JS and I can't seem to get pass this error. Can anyone provide any insight as to why I'm getting this error?

```
var book = {
    year: 2004,
    edition:1,
    get newYear(){
        return "Hello, it's " + this.year;
    },
    set newYear(y, e){
        this.year = y;
        this.edition = e;
    }
};
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Setter must have exactly one formal parameter

Comment: you should be setting on parameter, not two. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The setter function is called when you assign the value that setter represent:

```
var obj = {
  set a(newVal) { console.log("hello"); }
}
obj.a = 1; // will console log "hello"
```

As you can see it doesn't make sense for a setter to take multiply arguments, but it gives you the freedom to manipulate the value before it is set:

```
var person = {
  surname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  get fullname() {
    return this.surname + " " + this.lastname;
  },
  set fullname(fullname) {
    fullname = fullname.split(' ');
    this.surname = fullname[0];
    this.lastname = fullname[1];
  }
};

console.log(person.fullname); // "John Doe"
person.fullname = "Jane Roe";
console.log(person.surname); // "Jane"
console.log(person.lastname); // "Roe"
```

Comment: This is very true and a good example of how to use setters/getters, but you need to tie this into the actual question by offering some solution.

Answer (score 7):

A *setter* function is a function that's called implicitly when you do something like:

```
someObject.property = 25;
```

Because an assignment operation involves assigning one and only one value, a setter function must have a single argument. It will only ever be called (via the implicit assignment mechanism) with one argument anyway, so a two-argument setter makes little sense.

In your case, you could make your setter take a single object and get the two values out of it:

```
var book = {
    year: 2004,
    edition:1,
    get newYear(){
        return "Hello, it's " + this.year;
    },
    set newYear(value){
        this.year = value.y;
        this.edition = value.e;
    }
};
```

Then you can say

```
book.newYear = { y: 2005, e: 2 };
```

(Personally I think I'd prefer to do that with destructuring assignment, but it would work.)

Comment: Actually maybe destructuring assignment *can't* do this - can it? I feel like one of those times where you can't remember if the word "rhythm" is real.

Comment: I would go with not using a property in this case, just a method called `setNewYear(y,e)`. I can't quite put my finger on it, but a setter like that just doesn't seem to be  how they are typically used. I also thought of a destructuring assignment but couldn't figure out how to use it in this case.

Comment: @JuanMendes yes I agree, I wouldn't do it. I was mostly just contriving an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try setNewYear and not set newYear and the same for getNewYear not get newYear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all the above answers are all good and work fine. In spite of all these, you can simply specify one setter for setting one value and another for setting another value. Like this:

```
var book = {
    year: 2004,
    edition: 1,
    get newYear() {
        return "Hello, it's " + this.year;
    },
    set newYear(y) {
        this.year = y;
    },
    set newEdition(e) {
        this.edition = e
    }

};
book.newYear = 3232
book.edition = 3
console.log(book)
```