# ES6 setter function isn't recognized

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm studying the new syntax of ES6 and now I'm looking through `get` and `set` methods and I got an error when trying to use `set` method.

Here is an example:

```js
  class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    get fullName() {
      return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
    
    set fullName(...value) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }
  }
    
  let a = new Person('Person','A');
  a.fullName('Person','B')
  console.log(a);
```

Comment: Does the *fullName* getter work?

Comment: You should read more about getters and setters. You are not using them `set` correctly. Specifically, calling the property won't work unless it is a function.

Comment: yes get method works

Comment: The answer you have chosen is technically correct but is misleading. It contains terrible coding practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getters and setters are not used as standard functions. According to MDN:

> The set syntax binds an object property to a function to be called
>   when there is an attempt to set that property.

You should use the normal `=` assignment to invoke the setter, and not call it as a function.

In addition, the setter accepts only one paramter, and it can't use the rest (...) syntax. You can use an array of or an object, and use destructuring assignment to achieve that.

```js
class Person {

  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  
  set fullName([firstName, lastName]) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}

let a = new Person('Person','A');

a.fullName = ['Person', 'B'];

console.dir(a);
```

Comment: That is true, but passing an array makes no sense. He clearly has a syntax error. `a.fullName('Person','B')`.

Comment: Passing an array of values to pass multiple values into a setter is wrong unless the getter also returns an array.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - getters / setters is the ability to transform the data before assigning it, so the setter params doesn't have to be the same as the end value.

Comment: But the whole point is that these are transparent, logical field access operations. If the logical field is mutable, i.e. has a setter, then no one would expect to assign an array and get a string back.

Comment: You can say that about the API of any function that accept params of 1 type or several types, and return another. I used setters / getters only when I need to validate the data or transform it. In non JS languages I used the standard setters that you describe.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with that. Consider: `const fullName = a.fullName = ['Person', 'B'];`
`console.dir(fullName);`
`console.dir(a.fullName);` You are breaking the logical illusion that is the whole point of a property. The caller needs to think of `fullName` differently when they are writing vs reading and that is bad abstraction. My complaint is that this is bad code.

Comment: My point is that this is more of an opinion then a written in stone rules. I don't use triple assignment for example. I agree with you that it might be confusing, but it's possible, and sometimes needed.

Comment: It is fine to use an array (or tuple) as a property. It is also fine to have properties which can yield dramatically different kinds of values dynamically between accesses. What is problematic is that you have defeated the intention of `get` and `set` by placing the knowledge of internal representation with the caller by requiring them to pass an array into what they think of as a string.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't entirely new syntax. It is a variation of [ES5 setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Defining_a_setter_on_new_objects_in_object_initializers) that was applied to ES6 classes.

The whole point of `get`/`set`property accessors is that they are defined as property descriptor and used as ordinary property:

```
console.log(person.fullName);
person.fullName = 'Foo Bar';
```

And it should be:

```
set fullName(value) {
    const [firstName, lastName] = value.split(' ');
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

It makes no sense to define it as `set` setter if you want to use it as ordinary method. Instead, it can be

```
setFullName(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that `get` and `set` specify functions that are called when the property is read or written. The term property descriptor is not used quite correctly since a property descriptor does not need `get` or `set`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sure, they are called. Property descriptor [presumes `get` and `set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description). The question deliberately targets the problem with ES6, it doesn't intend to explain how descriptors work, that's common JS knowledge that isn't specific to ES6, there are answered questions on SO that address descriptors in detail.

Comment: @RobG Sorry, I didn't notice "ordinary method" remark in your comment. Yes, you are correct. Method signature was pasted from the OP, basically it should be `setFullName(firstName, lastName)` instead.

Comment: @estus they are called implicitly. They do not use call syntax. Indeed true that this has nothing to do with ES6, it was introduced in ES5, so +1 for that, but the code in the OP doesn't understand how getters and setters work so it does need to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a setter like that, see my snippet below and [see this answer for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815298/591257)

```js
class Person {
 constructor(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }

 get fullName() {
  return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
 }

 set fullName(fname) {
        let fn = fname.split(' ');
  this.firstName = fn[0];
  this.lastName = fn[1];
 }
}

let a = new Person('Person','A');
a.fullName = 'Person B';
console.dir(a);
```